# How to increment an auto-increment field with ADO.NET in C#

Tags: c#, ado.net, auto-increment

I have a database table with three fields:

**Product(ProdId, Name, Price)**

Where *ProdId* is a **auto-increment** field. The auto-increment is with seed 1, starting from 0.

I perform operation on the database by using C# in an ASP.NET application.

If I use LINQ to INSERT a new record I just assign values to Name and Price fields and when I submit the changes the database is responsible to increment the ProdId.

How can I do it with the standard ADO.NET? If I write an INSERT statement

```
INSERT INTO Product (Name, Price) VALUES (@Name, @Price)
```

when I execute the command an exception is thrown;

**Cannot insert NULL in ProdId.**

Anybody has a solution? Thanks

Comment: This surely works, no matter if you use ADO, Linq, EF etc. Are you really sure that command is executed against same DB/table?

Comment: At the Table Product using SQL Server Management Studio at Table Designer after you opened the Product Table put Identity Column ProdId that should solve you're problem .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would start debugging in this order:

- Make sure in your SQL you do have AUTO Increment on

[image]

**Data Types** can be `numeric`, `money`, `decimal`, `float`, `bigint` and `int`

- using the Studio Management tool, run the insert query manually

like:

```
DECLARE @Name nvarchar(100), @Price money

SET @Name = 'Bruno Alexandre';
SET @Price = 100.10;

INSERT INTO Product (Name, Price) VALUES (@Name, @Price)
```

or

```
INSERT INTO Product SELECT @Name, @Price
```

- **Make SURE** that you are pointing in your ADO Connection to the correct Database.
- If using EF, **refresh your table** using the Update Table Wizard on the `.edmx` file

Answer (score 1):

How did you define the ProdId, try INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ...